# Where can I find the full implementation of std::string::find()?

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm looking to find out why it is that every single implementation of a string searching algorithm I've written so far is quite a bit worse than the one provided by `std::string`.

Not only is it better, but it seems to perform in constant time (by constant I mean it varies very little depending on the size of the string and/or substring) regardless of whether I've split the load among threads.

Here be my compiler:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So far, I've managed to dig up `basic_string.tcc` located in `/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits`, which yields this for `std::string::find`:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
    typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
    basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
    find(_CharT __c, size_type __pos) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    {
        size_type __ret = npos;
        const size_type __size = this->size();
            if (__pos < __size)
            {
                const _CharT* __data = _M_data();
                const size_type __n = __size - __pos;
                const _CharT* __p = traits_type::find(__data + __pos, __n, __c);
                if (__p)
                __ret = __p - __data;
            }
        return __ret;
    }
```

The only thing I'm missing at the moment is found on this line:

```
const _CharT* __p = traits_type::find(__data + __pos, __n, __c);
```

So does anyone have any idea where I might find the implementation of `traits_type::find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found:

- [a general one](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L166),
- [one for `char`](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L265),
- [one for `wchar_t`](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L336),
- [one for `char16_t`](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L336),
- and [one for `char32_t`](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h#L520).

The `char`/`wchar_t` ones just call the C (builtin) functions, and I notice now they could optimize one of the `char16_t`/`char32_t` ones using the same specialization as `wchar_t` which should be the same size as one of these two types on most platforms.